# How to check a variable value is in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How to check php variable with array?

When `$user_check = "ccc";`

```
<?php
    $user_group = array('aaa' , 'bbb' , 'ccc' , 'ddd');
    $name_group = join("','",$user_group); 

    if ($name_group != $user_check) { 
        echo "not found." 
    } else { 
        echo "found." 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `in_array()`

```
if (in_array($user_check,$user_group))
{ echo "found."; }
else
{ echo "Not found."; }
```

Check the documentation on this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: +1 , Link the documentation too.

Comment: please add semicolon after echo statement. other then it will give an error.

Comment: Not critical, but this could simplified to a one liner: `echo in_array($user_check,$user_group) ? 'found' : 'not found'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array` Function

```
if ( in_array($user_check, $user_group) ) {
   echo "found."
} else { 
  echo "not found."
}
```

Comment: Your code returns `found.` in both cases.

Comment: thanks .. this just missed in typiing :)